# Tool to work with dataflow easier/more visual

Tags: data-visualization, python

I've written some Python code which does some (network) data analysis. It's mostly large data coming from SQL where I play around with statistics and algorithms.

However configuring the interplay between modules and tracking/debugging what's going on with the data isn't very convenient.
Do you know a tool which could nicely display the dataflow modules, with maybe some tooltip information, some table data browser etc.? Something where I could incorporate my Python code and display table-like data.

Comment: I don't have the privileges to migrate posts... but I'd suggest searching the S.O. site. Maybe look into R which is very good for graphing, and can interact with Python, too. Good luck!

Comment: It's not so much about programming frameworks or plotting. It's rather the other way round of using a tool visual dataflow tool which I can extend with my data transformation scripts.

Comment: Meanwhile I found interesting options. http://orange.biolab.si/ Not sure if that's what I need...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Orange](http://orange.biolab.si) is an excellent framework for data analysis that contains many ready-to-use building blocks, including [SQL interface](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/reference/Orange.data.sql/) and including [nice interface](http://orange.biolab.si/screenshots/) to connect the different building blocks one with another. 
For example: 
[image]

These framework is very much extensible. You can write any classifier/regression method/whatever in pure python and plug it in. It takes some time to get used to the data model (both objects and data files), but once you get it, everything is pretty much straight forward. The weakest link of Orange is model precision: not all the classifiers can be easily saved to the disk and none of them (of those I'm aware of) can be serialized using the GUI. I have never needed this option, as I work with orange almost exclusively outside the GUI so maybe I'm wrong at this particular point.

Comment: Thanks :) I had also found this some time later (see commments). Can it show SQL-like tables or better any given Python data easily? Can I use my mostly custom Python analysis blocks. I'll surely give it a try.

Comment: @Gerenuk see my edits

Comment: I use Orange a lot too, but like @bgbg, by importing the package and writing code, not using the GUI. When I write such code, I use the Spyder IDE, which provides a GUI "variable explorer". This is a different use case than the OP described, but is one more tool in the toolbox for having a rich scientific Python environment.  See http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/wiki/Features